# convert output of find command into array of strings in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to simulate the following unix commands:

```
f=`find . -name "*.pdf"`
for file in $f; do echo "$f"; done
```

I have the following python command:

```
out= subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/find", ".", "-name",  "*.pdf"]).strip()
```

But I can't access `out[0]` or `out[1]` and so on. Is it possible to return the output in python as an array of strings, so I can iterate over each of them and do something with it? Thanks

Comment: Why, when `os.walk()` is a thing?

Comment: This is just an example I came up with to illustrate what I want. To rephrase this in another way - I want to execute a command which returns output, and I want to iterate over each line in that output generated. So `os.walk()` wouldn't help in that use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) remove spaces around the string. You need to [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to split lines:

```
>>> 'a\nb'.strip()
'a\nb'
>>> 'a\nb\n'.splitlines()
['a', 'b']
```

---

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/find", ".", "-name",  "*.pdf"]).splitlines()
```

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No, the use of `strip` is incorrect, and the use of `splitlines()` is wrong if `find` ever outputs a file name which contains a newline.  The safe, reliable way is to use `find -print0` and split on nulls.  This is a FAQ.

Comment: @tripleee How do u split on nulls?

Comment: @Bill, `line.split('\0')` (`'\0'` means null character)

Comment: @tripleee, Thank you for pointing filenames with newline. BTW, if OP really want to list files, OP could use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) instead of `subprocess.*`. `str.strip` was used to demonstrate that the method is not what OP want.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if python has something special for null characters.